# Nested Function in a Class, Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, nested

I am trying to have Nested function inside a class. Here is my coad

```
class big():
        def __init__(self):
        self.mas = "hello"

    def update(self):

        def output(self):
            print(self.mas)

        self.output()

thing = big()

thing.update()
```

However when it runs I get an error that output is not defined. How can i run the output function inside the update function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call it as `output()`, without `self`.  The way you've defined it, it basically is a local variable inside your `update` method, not an attribute of the class.

```
class big():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mas = "hello"

    def update(self):
        def output():
            print(self.mas)

        output()

thing = big()

thing.update()
```

Comment: You should probably not have `self` as arg to `output`, but if you do, you should pass it with the call. As it stands, it raises `TypeError: output() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque My mistake, fixed it